# Looking up a value from 1 table in a lower and higher value range on another table dependent on a category

Tags: sql

Good day,

I have 3 tables T1 Fact ,T2 Dim Cat and T3 Dim Range and would like to lookup a value from T1 depending on the category T2 (there are 2 columns that could be used depending on the Category) and T3 have, a range on T3 with a lower and a higher value and populate a unique ID on T1.

e.g

Table Designs:

[image]

How do I formulate the Syntax to do the lookup depending on the category and between the two values that my output Column (range ID) is as follows:

[image]

Kind Regards and thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint:  `join`, but with inequality.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: thank you for the response SQL Aginity Netezza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi comparing NULL makes it hard.

In Oracle this will work. I don't know what SQL you are using but maybe you have to change it a little:

This is including record with t1.id = 2:

```
SELECT t1.id
,      t1.code
,      t1.result_value
,      t1.result_text
,      t3.id as range_id
FROM t1
,    t2
,    t3
WHERE t1.code = t2.code
AND   t2.category = t3.category
AND (  t1.result_value BETWEEN t3.range_lower AND t3.range_higher
    OR NVL(t1.result_value,999) = NVL(t3.range_lower,999)
    );
```

This is with values in columns t1.result_value, t3.range_lower and t3.range_higher (gives 2 records):

```
SELECT t1.id
,      t1.code
,      t1.result_value
,      t1.result_text
,      t3.id as range_id
FROM t1
,    t2
,    t3
WHERE t1.code = t2.code
AND   t2.category = t3.category
AND   t1.result_value BETWEEN t3.range_lower AND t3.range_higher
;
```

After your comment:

```
SELECT t1.id
,      t1.code
,      t1.result_value
,      t1.result_text
,      t3.id as range_id
FROM t1
,    t2
,    t3
WHERE t1.code = t2.code
AND   t2.category = t3.category
AND (  t1.result_value BETWEEN t3.range_lower AND t3.range_higher
    OR t1.result_text = t3.range_name
    );
```

You could also add CASE to the where clause.

Comment: thank you for your response when looking at Cat B it should look at t1 result Text and t3 range Name

Comment: Thank you using your scripts I was able to solve the issue please see below instead of doing it in the where clause I did it in the Join:  FROM CDW_PROD.INFAETL.FCT_T1S a
join CDW_PROD.INFAETL.DIM_T2 b
on (a.TEST_METHOD_ID = b.TEST_METHOD_ID)
left Join CDW_PROD.ADMIN.DIM_T3 c
on (b.TEST_CATEGORY = c.TEST_CATEGORY)
and case 
when b.TEST_CATEGORY in ('Cat1','Cat2') then a.RESULT_NUMERIC BETWEEN c.LOW_VALUE AND c.HIGH_VALUE 
when b.TEST_CATEGORY = 'Cat3' then a.RESULT_CONFORMED = RESULT_RANGE_DISPLAY_CASE
else false end